# Which opensource tool is best?

Tags: reporting

In my application i have to create report.I don't know which opensource reporting tool is best either jassper report or pentaho report.If anyone has idea about this please share your view. And In what are the aspect jasperreport is differ with pentaho.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend the [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) reporting tool. myDBR allows you to create your reports within minutes and can easily be integrated to your existing web-application.